# C++: algorithm that uses fixed-size buffer of data that are produced in stream, faster than the algorithm speed; modified version

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

This is a, I hope, an improved version of [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286131/c-algorithm-that-uses-fixed-size-buffer-of-data-that-are-produced-in-stream), limiting atomic usage (following @GSliepen, @G.Sliepen advice) (NB I'm limited to, at most C++17):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// #define LOG
// #define USEACTIVESLEEP

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
#define MAYBEUNSUSED(var) static_cast<void>(var)
// functions to sleep for short period of times
// active wait but thread sleep has a too large overhead to allow for short
// delays
namespace {
// Iterations per nanosec
double gk_ItPerns;

void EstimateItPerns() noexcept {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    constexpr std::size_t NbIt{1000000};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NbIt; ++i) {
        volatile std::size_t DoNotOptimize = 0;
        MAYBEUNSUSED(DoNotOptimize);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto delay =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start)
            .count();
    gk_ItPerns = static_cast<double>(NbIt) / static_cast<double>(delay);
}

void ActiveSleep(double i_ns) noexcept {
    std::size_t NbIt = static_cast<std::size_t>(i_ns * gk_ItPerns);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NbIt; ++i) {
        volatile std::size_t DoNotOptimize = 0;
        MAYBEUNSUSED(DoNotOptimize);
    }
}
}  // namespace
#endif

class CAsyncAlgo {
   public:
    using Data_t = std::size_t;

   private:
    static constexpr std::size_t mNbData = 1024;

    std::size_t mWorkingIndex = 1;
    std::size_t mBufferIndex = 0;

    // type of data buffer
    using DataBuffer_t = std::array<Data_t, mNbData>;

    std::size_t mIndex = 0;
    bool mHasData = false;

    std::array<DataBuffer_t, 2> mSamples;

    // Mutex for condition_variable and atomics
    std::mutex mMutex;
    // Condition variable used to wake up the working thread
    std::condition_variable mWakeUp;
    // To stop the worker
    std::atomic<bool> mStop{false};
    // Is an Algo instance running?
    std::atomic<bool> mBusy{false};
    // 1- Can an Algo instance be launched (for testing spurious wake-up)?
    // not atomic because always accessed inside critical section
    bool mReady{false};

    // working thread
    std::thread Worker;

    // WorkLoad internals
    // previous seen max value in buffer
    Data_t mMaxVal = 0;
    // number of processed data
    Data_t mProcessed = 0;

   private:
    bool Stop() const noexcept {
        // 2- no synch needed?
        return (mStop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }
    bool Ready() const noexcept { return (mReady); }
    void WaitForJob() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "entering waiting state " << std::boolalpha << mStop
                  << std::endl;
#endif
        // 3- std::memory_order_relaxed possible as locking mMutex will prevent
        // it to be reordered before the previous Workload call
        mBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
        mWakeUp.wait(lock, [this]() -> bool { return (Stop() || Ready()); });
        assert(lock.owns_lock());
        assert(mBusy || Stop());
        mReady = false;
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "waked up " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
#endif
    }
    // Check if the working buffer is holding increasing successive integers
    // from some point max value must be strictly greater than the one of the
    // previous call {5,6,7,3,4} is valid if previous greatest value is strictly
    // smaller than 7 {5,6,7,2,4} is invalid smallest value must also be
    // strictly greater than mMaxVal as buffers do not overlap
    void WorkLoad() {
        Data_t Max = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][mNbData - 1];
        Data_t Min = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][0];
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < mNbData; ++i) {
            if (mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i] !=
                mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1] + 1) {
                assert(mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1] ==
                       (mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i] + mNbData - 1));
                Max = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i - 1];
                Min = mSamples[mWorkingIndex][i];
            }
        }
        assert(Max > mMaxVal);
        assert(Min > mMaxVal);
        mMaxVal = Max;
        mProcessed += mNbData;
    }
    void MainLoop() {
        while (!Stop()) {
            WaitForJob();
            if (Stop()) {
                return;
            }
            WorkLoad();
        }
    }

   public:
    CAsyncAlgo() : Worker([this]() mutable -> void { MainLoop(); }) {}
    void Push(Data_t const Sample, std::size_t) {
        // writing one sample in current circular buffer
        mSamples[mBufferIndex][mIndex] = Sample;
        mIndex = (mIndex + 1) % mNbData;
        if (mIndex == 0) {
            // buffer is full
            mHasData = true;
        }
    }
    bool IsReady() {
        if (mHasData && (mBusy.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void SubmitJob() {
#ifdef LOG
        std::cout << "SubmitJob" << std::endl;
#endif
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            mReady = true;
            // 4- std::memory_order_relaxed because no synch needed, read only
            // by this thread
            mBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            std::swap(mWorkingIndex, mBufferIndex);
            mIndex = 0;
            mHasData = false;
        }
        mWakeUp.notify_one();
    }
    void Run(double const, double &) const {
        // NOP
    }

    // destructor
    ///\details finishing computation and releasing resources
    ///\todo explicitely "close" computation before the end of life of the
    /// object
    ~CAsyncAlgo() {
        {
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "closing" << std::endl;
#endif
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            // 5- std::memory_order_relaxed: on unlocking may synchronise with
            // the lock in wait in this case, the worker will see true
            mStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        mWakeUp.notify_one();
        if (Worker.joinable()) {
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "waiting for last run" << std::endl;
#endif
            Worker.join();
#ifdef LOG
            std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
#endif
            std::cout << "Processed " << GetNbProcessed() << " data"
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::size_t GetNbProcessed() { return mProcessed; }
};

static constexpr std::size_t NbSamples = 1000000;

int main() {
    CAsyncAlgo Algo;

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
    EstimateItPerns();
    std::size_t acc{0};
#endif
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NbSamples; ++i) {
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
        double period = 10000.;  // ns
        // manage data production frequency
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#endif
        CAsyncAlgo::Data_t data =
            static_cast<CAsyncAlgo::Data_t>(i + 1);  // 0 is reserved
        Algo.Push(data, i);
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        // no more synchro needed as only this thread is designed to launch a
        // new computation
        if (static_cast<double>(
                std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end -
                                                                     start)
                    .count()) < period) {
            ActiveSleep(
                period -
                static_cast<double>(
                    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end -
                                                                         start)
                        .count()));
        }
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        acc = acc + static_cast<std::size_t>(
                        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
                            end - start)
                            .count());
#endif
        if (Algo.IsReady()) {
#ifdef LOG
#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
            std::cout << "Ready " << i << " "
                      << static_cast<double>(acc) /
                             (static_cast<double>(i) + 1.)
                      << " us/Sample" << std::endl;
#endif
#endif
            Algo.SubmitJob();
        }
        double res;
        Algo.Run(3.14, res);
    }

#ifdef USEACTIVESLEEP
    std::cout << static_cast<double>(acc) / NbSamples << "us/Sample"
              << std::endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/qfzsM96Mo)
One atomic has been replaced by a simple bool as it was only accessed in critical sections.
The other where kept due to access out of critical sections but with less constraint memory order as, once again, when inside such sections, they provides enough synchronization and ordering constraints.

Separating buffers management from workflow would still have to be done.

Yet I'd just like to have feedback on remaining comments (1 to 5)

Comment: Have you tested `ActiveSleep`? What is the origin of the realtime requirement? Most cases when I thought spinning is required were solved with properly specifying the workflow with flow graphs and let task scheduler (both libraries like TBB and the OS scheduler) to do their job. If the worker is sleeping most of the time, the producer thread might as well do the tasks itself.

Comment: It was just a way to test some quite high frequency timing that were not possible with a mere sleep. I think it's not significant with respect to my questions about synchronization and I merely let it in case reviewer would like to explore different timing situations...
By the way I'm interested if there is a way to have passive sleep of the order of 10 us or less.

Comment: Probably some operating system allows for such a quick sleep. There are two situations - when the hardware thread is actually asleep (i.e. idle, no more OS threads scheduled) and when it is occupied by another OS thread. Second case is likely solveable with some Real-Time Operating System (RTOS). The first case usually lets the CPU to go to lower power C-states which lets it conserve energy. Probably disabling C-states in CMOS will solve the issue. You might want to read [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/273339/93301) for some insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large part of [my answer to your previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286132/129343) still applies. I'll revisit some of it below, but first lets start with the changes and the remaining questions.

## Can we remove all atomics?

I already mentioned that you should avoid mixing mutexes and atomic variables. That still applies. You have two atomic variables left. Inside `WaitForJob()` and `SubmitJob()`, those variables are accessed with the mutex held. There are a few places where these atomic variables are read while not holding a mutex. We can avoid needing those reads by having `WaitForJob()` return the value of `mStop`, and by creating a `TrySubmitJob()` that itself check `mReady`:

```
class CAsyncAlgo {
    …
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mWakeUp;
    bool mStop{false};
    bool mBusy{false};
    …
    bool WaitForJob() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
        mBusy = false;
        mWakeUp.wait(lock, [&]{ return mStop || mReady; });
        mReady = false;
        return !mStop;
    }

    void TrySubmitJob() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            if (!mHasData || mBusy)
                return;
            mReady = true;
            mBusy = true
            std::swap(mWorkingIndex, mBufferIndex);
            mIndex = 0;
            mHasData = false;
        }
        mWakeUp.notify_one();
    }

    void MainLoop() {
        while (WaitForJob())
            WorkLoad();
    }
    …
};
```

Note how `MainLoop()` has simplified a lot. `WaitForJob()` does less atomic operations now, so it's actually more efficient.

The only issue is that `TrySubmitJob()` will always lock the mutex, while `if (Algo.IsReady()) Algo.SubmitJob()` avoided locking the mutex if the consumer was still busy. So if you are going to call this every time you `Push()` one number to the buffer, then it probably is worth it to keep `mBusy` as an atomic variable. However, its value quickly diminishes if you do a lot more work between calls to `TrySubmitJob()`.

## Questions in the comments

> `// 1- Can an Algo instance be launched (for testing spurious wake-up)?`

I don't know what you mean by this.

> ```
> // 2- no synch needed?
> return (mStop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
> ```

It's probably fine here because you check it in `WaitForJob()` with the mutex held as well, and it's only ever set with a held mutex, so that will ensure things will be synchronized. For the two calls of `Stop()` that are done without the mutex held: the first one is just an unnecessary check (it looks like an optimization, but because it is mostly `false` for most of the time your program runs, it's actually a pessimization), the second will be guaranteed to see `true` if `WaitForJob()` saw that it was `true`. As mentioned above, it's better if you make this non-atomic.

> ```
> // 3- std::memory_order_relaxed possible as locking mMutex will prevent
> // it to be reordered before the previous Workload call
> mBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
> ```

This is not true. Locking the mutex is a `std::memory_order_acquire` action. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> `memory_order_acquire`: A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered **before** this load. All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread […]

Note the emphasis. The write to `mBusy` cannot be reordered **before** the acquire action *on the mutex*. But whatever `WorkLoad()` is doing has nothing to do with the mutex nor `mBusy`. Reads and writes from `WorkLoad()` could be reordered to after the locking of the mutex (at least as seen from other threads).

It will still be OK in your code: at worst `SubmitJob()` is called too early, but since it takes the mutex as well, it will at least not run before `WaitForJob()` has released its mutex.

> ```
> // 4- std::memory_order_relaxed because no synch needed, read only
> // by this thread
> mBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
> ```

One of the `assert()` calls in `WaitForJob()` reads `mBusy`, so it's *not* "read only by this thread" unless you compile with assertions disabled (this might thus be a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)). Apart from that it's fine.

> ```
> // 5- std::memory_order_relaxed: on unlocking may synchronise with
> // the lock in wait in this case, the worker will see true
> mStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
> ```

See comment 2.

Using atomics correctly is tricky, especially if you want to have the most relaxed memory ordering possible. Your intution might fail you. What works fine on one architecture might not work on another. I think your reasoning is incorrect in some cases, and that might lead to bugs. I personally would stick to using release/acquire semantics, or just purely relying on mutexes instead of atomics, as that is easier to understand.

## Separate the data structure from the workers

Again, the `class CSyncAlgo` is too complicated, making it harder to understand, and making it less flexible. I strongly suggest you split things up. Create a class that just manages the buffers, then you can have two threads that access an object of that class. Consider being able to write:

```
int main() {
    DoubleBuffer<std::size_t, 1024> dblbuf;

    std::thread producer([&]{
        for (…) {
            …
            dblbuf.Push(data, i);
            dblbuf.TrySubmit();
            …
        }
        dblbuf.Stop();
    });

    std::thread consumer([&]{
        while (dblbuf.WaitForJob()) {
            for (…) {
                …
                auto sample = dblBuf.Pop(i);
                …
            }
        }
    });

    consumer.join();
    producer.join();
}
```

## Consider using at least three buffers for better performance

The way your code works now, it checks for every sample written if it can call `SubmitJob()`. Even if you do this with an atomic variable, it's still one atomic operation per sample. It would be better if you would not have to do this per-sample check. If you have three buffers, then the producer can write a full buffer, and then swap to another buffer. This way, you only need a check for one full buffer.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. 1 was a typo, I forgot to remove it.
Regarding 5: the function are inlined. I'm unsure of the reordering possibilities in presence of loops. Thus my remark was about the store being reordered before the ```Workload()``` call at previous iteration. This is actually made impossible by the acquire nature of the ```lock()```. Yet, what are reordering possibilities in presence of loop?

Comment: Inlining doesn't change the possibilities of reordering. In the presence of the loop, you have to unroll the loop to see what reordering possibilities there are. You then will notice it's not just the acquire of the `lock()`, but there is also the release of the `unlock()`. A mutex works because of the combination of both the `lock()` and `unlock()` ensuring proper synchronization with another thread that also uses that same mutex. Don't rely on `lock()` being an acquire to magically transfer that property to a different atomic variable. It may work on some architectures, but isn't guaranteed.

Comment: My reasoning was the following : when, in the same thread, you have a mutex lock followed by an expression, this expression cannot be reordered before the lock, otherwise, if the lock synchronizes with an unlock in another thread, the "synchronise-with" relationship would be broken. Yet I'm unconfortable with this reasoning.
There is a consensus to say that what is between lock and the next unlock (in the same thread) remains there. There is several questions on SO on this point but the answer were more interpretation than actual "legal" arguments. The more plausible I found was about the...

Comment: ... synchronize with relationship consequences on reordering within the same thread.
Clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: regarding inlining, without it, the compiler won't see the content of some function and cannot make assumption about the absence of fences and edge effect. My own assumption is that in cannot reordered expressions "on the other side" of a not inlined function call. Is it true? What whould be the standard wording on this point?

Comment: hum this inlining issue seems more complex than anticipated. Some answers on SO are telling that a not inlined function call implies a compiler barrier but it may be different in presence of link time optimisation...

Comment: Regardless or not whether the *compiler* can reorder expressions, you also have to worry about the *CPU* reordering things. While x86 is very forgiving, the Arm architecture does a lot more reordering. And regardless of the architecture, the CPU can see all instructions generated by the compiler, and will happily reorder across function calls.

Comment: I'm deleting my comment about TrySubmitJob, you may want to delete your corresponding comment.